# Using javascript with model forms

Tags: javascript, playframework-2.0

I am getting values from a form and using those values to create Journey objects in my play project but I need to extend this so that I can add additional values in the background. Below is my current form which gets all the values from user input.

```
@form(routes.Application.createJourney()) {

    <fieldset>

    @inputText(journeyForm("start_loc"), '_label -> "Starting Location", 'placeholder -> "E.g. 1 Main Street")
    @inputText(journeyForm("end_loc"), '_label -> "End Location", 'placeholder -> "E.g. 1 High Street")
    @select(
        journeyForm("participant_type"), 
        options = options("Driver"->"Driver", "Passenger"->"Passenger"),
        '_label -> "Travel as",
        '_error -> journeyForm("participant_type").error.map(_.withMessage("Select participant type"))
        )
    @inputDate(journeyForm("date"), '_label -> "Date")
    @helper.input(journeyForm("Time")) { (id,name,value,args) => <input type="time" name="@name" id="@id" @toHtmlArgs(args)> } 

    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn primary"> 
    </div>
```

I'm not really sure how you can use javascript with these scala template generators and I have a javascript function that I want to use. Two of the inputs in my form are for locations, I want to be able to retrieve those locations with javascript to get their lat/lng values using Google Maps API. Below is the javascript for one location:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function codeAddress() {
    var geocoder;
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else {
        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
      }
    });
  }
  </script>
```

So there are two things I really need to do. Retrieve a inputText from the form for use in a javascript function. Use a variable in my javascript function to populate one of the form arguements in the background. Normally I would just a document.getElementByID but I don't think this will work with the form helper in play?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the id of the element with the form helper. Should not be a problem to retrieve it with javascript once its been rendered in the view.